# Self look up and Reporting Requirements

Tags: reporting, lookup

For one of my object (for e.g. Bug), we want a self lookup to the same object to store child records (for e.g. Child Bugs).

After that I created a custom report type on Bug with child object Bug. I am able to see reports like any other look up relationship. I am able to use Functions in "Summary Report", where I can group by "Parent Bug".

**By this POC, I think that giving self lookup will not affect my reporting requirements in future.**

**Please suggest me, if anyone has got/experienced any issues in Reports while using Self look up in Salesforce.**

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish shukla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the self-lookups behave in the way that you're expecting.

Technically there no difference between lookups and self-lookups - so if you are good with the one, you should be good with the other.

But in my own experience, I usually wanted way more than the standard functionality provides:

- multiple levels of nestings (e.g. Bug D has parent C which has parent B which has parent A)
- automatic aggregation compared to rollup-summary on each bug with children (e.g. SumOfCost, SumOfEsitmatedEffortToFix, etc)

To get this, you probably will need a trigger to rollup the aggregations and also have to deal with limits (depending on structure and data volume).

Also keep in mind that it's probably a good idea to prevent cyclic relations e. g. Bug A has parent B which has parent A again. In my experience it's best to avoid such things unless you really need it.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe Heim, yes I have also written a trigger for getting the total on master record as summary rollup will not work with lookup. Thanks for your suggestion.